# All elements with margin 0 look different then * selector with margin 0

Tags: html, css, margin

can anyone explain why putting margins in each tag still leaves a space inbetween the article and header tag but when I use the * selector the space gets removed. I don't necessarily want all elements with a margin of zero. I would rather set each one I want to 0.

snippet 1 below leaves a space in between header and article tag

```
body
{
background-color: yellow;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#header
{
background-color: blue ;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
border: 3px solid black;
}

#article
{
background-color: red;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#search {
background-color: #a6dbed;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#mostdesired 
{
background-color: #c7d1d6;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

when I add this snippet below all spaces in between the article and header tag get removed, which is what I want, but I don't necessarily want 0 margin for all elements

```
*{ 
    margin: 0
}
```

Here is the html

```
<body>
    <header id="header">@*<h1>Welcome</h1>*@</header>
    <article id="article">
        <section id="search"><h2>this is the search</h2>@RenderBody()</section>
        <section id="mostdesired"><h2>This is the most section</h2></section>
    </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the margin for a bunch of elements, but not all of them, there are a couple of options. Here are two of them:

```
/* this gives all the desired elements the same margin */
#header, #article, #search, #mostdesired {
    margin: 0;
}

/* this gives all direct children of the body the same margin */
body > * {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I would also like to note that you don't need to have an id for your header element. Just use the `header` selector in your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

There are default margins on the `h1` and `h2` elements which are not affected by your CSS until you apply the `*` reset rule.

If it does not compromise your layout, it should be sufficient to apply zero margins to `h1, h2` as well. You can of course limit it using `#header h1, #article h2` or something similar just in case.

Answer (score 0):

An Asterisk (*) is the universal selector for CSS. Since this is a Universal Selector so every element used in  document will have a `margin:0`.

Also it is not a good practice to use universal selector in this way.

```
*{ margin: 0;}
```

Comment: Reading the question it's probably safe to assume the OP is aware of all this and doesn't actually intend to use `*` this way.

Answer (score -3):

```
body > * {
  margin: 0;
}
div,*{
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Are you trying to answer the question, or are you making a suggestion, or are you trying to edit the code yourself, or...?